# PHP multiple connections to MySQL - best practice

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have question about best practice of PHP Mysql connection.
For now i have a database with thousand of rows. This row contains for example description of product. But in row i don't have a name but ID of NAME, i don't have a color but ID of Color etc. I`m doing that way for cause when i must hange name, or color - then i'm only change name in table COLORS and ID of color stays the same. Is that way OK?

I'm asking because sometimes i have a problem with multiple connections to mysqli. Below i`m showing my way of work:

```
    // connection
        function getConnected($host,$user,$pass,$db) {

           $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
            $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
           if($mysqli->connect_error) 
             die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());


           return $mysqli;
        }

        function msq(){

            return getConnected('127.0.0.1','root','','database');

        }

// functions

function getcolor($temp){

   $db2=msq();

    if($result = $db2->query("SELECT * FROM linkcolor WHERE idcolor='$temp' ")){

            if($result->num_rows > 0) {

                $res = $result->fetch_assoc();

                return $res['name'];

            }else{
                return 'none';
            }

    }else{
        return 'none';
    }

}    

function getname($temp){

   $db2=msq();

    if($result = $db2->query("SELECT * FROM linkname WHERE idname='$temp' ")){

            if($result->num_rows > 0) {

                $res = $result->fetch_assoc();

                return $res['name'];

            }else{
                return 'none';
            }

    }else{
        return 'none';
    }

}  


    // query

    if($quer = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products")){

                    if($quer->num_rows > 0) {

                        while($qr = $quer->fetch_assoc()){

                         echo getcolor($qr['idcolor']);
                         echo getname($qr['idname']);

                        }

                    }else{

                    }

        }else{

    }
```

Is it a good way? Or better is to get data from mysql to array and then process them in function when i'm fetching my query?

Comment: The title of your question and the body itself don't match. Please clarify!

Comment: I think I understand what he's trying to do. Instead of getting results from one query, then getting results for another query... he wants to open two connections and setup two queries to access at the same time. Personally I would not do that... mysql and php is pretty darn good about handling results using just one connection per page request.

Comment: I'd honestly suggest that you use JOINS to get the extra columns from other tabls by the IDs: `SELECT p.*, n.name as LinkName, c.name as ColorName FROM products p LEFT JOIN linkname n ON p.idname = n.idname LEFT JOIN linkcolor c ON p.idcolor = c.idcolor`

Comment: Ask one question at a time.

Answer (score -1):

It is a bad praxis to make a connection for a single query, so multiple connections to the same database. Typically you make a single connection to one database at the start of your script and close it at the end. You can always use `$GLOBALS` to access a mysqli link you created or create a static class for that purpose:

```
static class DB {
    static protected $link = null;

    static public function getLink() {
        if (self::$link === null) {
            self::$link = msq();
        }
        return self::$link;
    }
}
```

then you can access your connection with

```
$db2 = DB::getLink();
```